# Named group + x modifier

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I use a named group in conjunction with the `x` regex modifier?

Works:

```
/(?<number>\d+)/ =~ 'hello here is a number 3298472398723'
puts number
```

Works:

```
regexp = /
  number  # this is a word
  \s      # this is a space
  (\d+)   # this is a bunch of numbers
/x
regexp =~ 'hello here is a number 3298472398723'
puts $1
```

Doesn't work:

```
regexp = /
  number  # this is a word
  \s      # this is a space
  (?<number>\d+)   # this is a bunch of numbers
/x
regexp =~ 'hello here is a number 3298472398723'
puts number
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing things up. `puts number` in the latter example does not work not because it’s extended regexp, but because it’s not inline.

`$~[:number]` or `Regexp.last_match[:number]` work always.

Direct reference works only for inline regexps:

```
▶ /
▷   number  # this is a word
▷   \s      # this is a space
▷   (?<number>\d+)   # this is a bunch of numbers
▷ /x =~ 'hello here is a number 11111'
#⇒ 16
▶ number
#⇒ "11111"
```

Here it perfectly works for extended regexp, because it’s inline.

**UPD** Thanks @Stefan, here is more precise requirement from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E):

> This assignment is implemented in the Ruby parser. The parser detects `regexp-literal =~ expression` for the assignment. The regexp must be a literal without interpolation and placed at left hand side.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E): *"The regexp must be a literal without interpolation and placed at left hand side."*

Comment: @Fuser97381 My name is not Matz, btw.